# How to calculate DOT week numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, but I have searched the other week number answers and haven't found a solution that works for multiple years.

The tire industry calculates week numbers starting with the first full week that begins on a Sunday. For example, in 2016 Week 1 commenced with 3 January. In 2017, Week 1 will begin on Sunday, 1 January. In 2018 Week 1 will start with Sunday, 3 January.

In Excel 2010, using returns type 1 and 17 (week starting on Sunday), 1 January for all three years is Week 1 when that should only be correct for `2017`. It should return Week `201552` for `2016` and `201653` for `2018`

I have tried the examples posted in other answers and also checked Ron de Bruin's page with his formulas for calculating the week number, but I've been unable to modify it correctly to get the formula to work consistently.

Here is Ron's example for calculating ISO week numbers:

```
=INT((B4-DATE(YEAR(B4-WEEKDAY(B4-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(B4-WEEKDAY(B4-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: Isn't the first Sunday in January 2018 the 7th?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(YEAR(B4) &TEXT(INT(DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(B4),1,AGGREGATE(15,6,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}/(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(B4),1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}))=1),1)),B4,"d")/7)+1,"00"),YEAR(B4)-1 &TEXT(INT(DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(B4)-1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}/(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(B4)-1,1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}))=1),1)),B4,"d")/7)+1,"00"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see this question has been answered way back but for future reference.....

I have previously posted formulas which give `ISO` week number - see [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/462829-weeknum-question.html#post2285411) ...and that formula can be adjusted depending on how the start day or date is defined, so to get the `YEAR&WEEKNUMBER` for a date in `A2` where week 1 starts on the first Sunday of the year you can use this formula

`=YEAR(A2+1-WEEKDAY(A2))&TEXT(INT((A2-WEEKDAY(A2)-DATE(YEAR(A2+1-WEEKDAY(A2)),1,7))/7)+2,"00")`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the simplest formula to accomplish the goal.  Basically, reference a date (cell D4 in this example) if the first day of the year for that date wasn't a Sunday, then return WeekNum - 1, otherwise return Weeknum.

=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(D4),1,1))>1,WEEKNUM(D4)-1,WEEKNUM(D4))